# WSO2 - FIX protocol - Sending requests to FIX gateway

Tags: wso2, fix-protocol

I am new to both wso2 and FIX protocol, my target is to send SOAP messages to a FIX gateway through WSO2. My understanding is that WSO2 will transform a soap message to fix syntax and sends the request then convert the response back to soap once a fix reply is received. My question is what about the login, logout and other session requests, will these be automatically sent by wso2? or should the backend application creates request for each? also what about the checksum field, is it automatically added by WSO2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIX transport of WSO2 ESB is based on the Quickfix/J FIX engine which supports all six major versions of the protocol. In two words, WSO2 is responsible of transforming a SOAP message to a FIX message and then sends it to the FIX engine. Once a response is received back, WSO2 will transform the FIX message to a SOAP message. Note that the SOAP message sent or received has the following format:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <message>
            <header>
                <field id="8"><![CDATA[FIX.4.0]]></field>
                <field id="9"><![CDATA[124]]></field>
                <field id="34"><![CDATA[2]]></field>
                <field id="35"><![CDATA[8]]></field>
                <field id="49"><![CDATA[EXEC]]></field>
                <field id="52"><![CDATA[20080326-10:03:17]]></field>
                <field id="56"><![CDATA[SYNAPSE]]></field>
            </header>
            <body>
                <field id="6"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="11"><![CDATA[1206525794862]]></field>
                <field id="14"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="17"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
                <field id="20"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="31"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="32"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="37"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
                <field id="38"><![CDATA[2]]></field>
                <field id="39"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
                <field id="54"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
                <field id="55"><![CDATA[DELL]]></field>
            </body>
            <trailer>
                <field id="10"><![CDATA[190]]></field>
            </trailer>
        </message>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So the developer should only transform his message (SOAP, JSON etc.) to a SOAP message using the above format and then do same for the response. As for the logon, heartbeat requests etc. these are handled by WSO2 internally and the developer should not worry about them. Same for the checksum, dont send a checksum and WSO2 will automatically generate it and append it to the FIX message. The developer should only enable FIX in axis2.xml configuration file and should create the proxy service (a lot of tutorials can be found only for this part) the best one is: https://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/06/fix-your-soa-wso2-esb/